# Java monitoring: JMX vs. Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, monitoring, jmx

I've learned a lot about JMX over the past couple of years and have built some pretty fancy MBeans for my web applications.  However, I'm not sure I have a good answer to a pretty basic question:

Why use JMX over simple HTTP servlets?

My current web applications offer redundant monitoring options:  I can access the data that needs to be monitored via JMX with a client like JConsole or I can access that same data in XML format via a servlet.  I don't see a strong reason to use one method over another, but the servlet method does have the major advantage of being readable by a simple http client / web browser.

I can see how JMX would be quite useful for Java applications that aren't web apps, but I can't see any advantage to using JMX for a web app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why use JMX over simple HTTP servlets?

From my standpoint, JMX is better for 3 reasons:

1. It requires less code to enable monitoring points.
2. It deals with Java serialized objects end-to-end so there is better data consistency.
3. It works with programs that are not servlet based (as you mentioned).

JMX offers a much easier interface to specific data items.  You can certainly write the same functionality in a number of servlets, but it is easier for me to expose those using JMX.

For example, if you are using Spring then you can use the `org.springframework.jmx.export` annotations (`@ManagedResource`, `@ManagedAttribute`, etc.) to mark up your classes.  I've also published my [SimpleJmx framework](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/) so you can easily expose attributes and operations with just a couple annotations independent of Spring.  For example:

```
@JmxResource(domainName = "j256", objectName = "lookupCache")
public class LookupCache {

    // this can also be done as @JmxAttributeMethod on the getter/setters
    @JmxAttributeField(description = "Number of hits in the cache")
    private int hitCount;
    ...

    @JmxOperation(description = "Flush the cache")
    public void flushCache() {
       ...
    }
}
```

I have a [fully working example program](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/simplejmx/code/trunk/src/test/java/com/j256/simplejmx/server/ExampleTest.java) to see how it works.  So all you need to do to expose a value or operation is add an annotation to the class and each attribute and/or method.  The code to publish it using SimpleJmx looks like the following.  Spring is similar albeit with beans:

```
// create a new server listening on port 8000
JmxServer jmxServer = new JmxServer(8000);
jmxServer.start();
// register our lookupCache object defined above
jmxServer.register(lookupCache);
```

To get similar functionality in servlets would take a lot more code than just annotations.  That said, there may exist frameworks which provide similar functionality in servlet land that I don't know about.

Some more notes:

- There are probably better monitoring tools that grok HTTP/HTML but there are also a ton of distributed JMX monitoring applications.  Probably a toss up.
- Being able to programmatically get *objects* from JMX servers is a plus as opposed to just strings from a servlet page.  [SimpleJmx](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/) also supports a simple JMX client although better ones exist out there.
- Obviously a lot of other worthwhile data is already published by the JVM by default: VM settings, thread details, memory information, etc..

Answer (score 3):

In addition to reading values, JMX can be used to invoke methods on Management Beans.

For example, we often use it to force a JVM garbage collection for Tomcat instances remotely.

Also because JMX is a different port that http/https you can limit access at the network level via firewalls. JMX has built-in username/password authentication as well.

A web servlet would have to implement it's own access control.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion JMX is overrated and it can be tricky to configure.
If your application is already a webcontainer I think you should definitely go for a simple servlet.

A tiny [servlet approach like nudge4j](https://github.com/lorenzoongithub/nudge4j) would give you everything and more.